# Why my onStart() function is not working at start of the main activity of my project?

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue when i am running onStart method at the starting of my main activity. My onstart method is not checking if condition thus whenever i am opening my application i am always been directing to register_activity of my project which is not acceptable because i want that only those users who are new they must be direct to registerr_activity and not the one who are already been exist in database.

```
                         package com.example.bookstore;

                           import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

                           import android.content.Intent;
                           import android.os.Bundle;
                           import android.os.SystemClock;

                           import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
                           import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

                           public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                           private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

                           @Override
                           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                           firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); accessing firebashauth object
                           SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                           Intent register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register_Activity.class);
                           startActivity(register); 

                           //here register intent will shift from 
                           mainactivity to register_activity after 3000 ms

                           finish(); here finishing the register intent
                             }

                          @Override
                          protected void **onStart()** {
                          super.onStart();

                        **FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();**

                           ***if (currentUser == null)* {
                          Intent registerintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
                          Register_Activity.class);
                           startActivity(registerintent);
                           finish();
                           } 

                            else {
                           *Intent homeactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home_Activity.class);
                           startActivity(homeactivity);
                           finish();*
                            }**
           This if condition is not checking in onStart method and thus due to this i am always directing to register_activity.
                              }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per android lifecycle onCreate() is called before onStart(). 
In your code inside onCreate() you are doing

```
Intent register = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register_Activity.class);
startActivity(register);
```

So, it will always go to the Register activity even before checking the logic inside onStart().
To fix this problem, remove the above lines from onCreate().

Comment: Oh thank you soo much.its Work! but i have another question. If i  put the logic (if condition) code in the onCreate() method then i am getting the desired output but what is the advantage of using onStart() method or where should i use onStart() method?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do that. If you want any action to happen once during the activity creation, then put it under onCreate() but say you want a check to happen even if the activity is resumed then put it under onResume().

Comment: Fo detailed understanding of the android lifecycle, you can refer to this documentation. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: and what about onStart()

Comment: onStart() is the state after onCreate() and before onResume(). This is the state where the activity becomes visible and interactive to the user. So if an app wants to update some ui state, then that can be done here.